# How to calculate odds ratios and probabilities in case-control studies?

Tags: odds-ratio, odds, case-control-study

I came across this study, [*Case-control study of stroke and the quality of hypertension control in north west England*](http://www.bmj.com/content/314/7076/272). In this study I find numerous odds ratio.

As far as I understand, all the `Case` are eventful (with stroke) because they recruited them from a stroke registry already; while the `Control` are people with similar demographics to `Case` but without strokes.

[image: Odds ratio extracted from the study]

Questions:

1. How is the crude odds ratio calculated?

   e.g. In the category `<140`, I calulated $OR = \frac{23/43}{101/287}=1.519\neq1.7$.
2. Is it possible to calculate probability from **adjusted OR**?

   Can we say $Odds(\text{not hypertensive})=101/287=0.3519$.

   So the $Adjusted\;Odds(<140)=1.3\times0.3519=0.4575$. And event probability $p=\frac{0.4575}{1+0.4575}=0.3139$?

Comment: I do not suppose the calculation to be different just because it is a case-control studies. But it seems to me this way so I titled this post with "in case-control studies".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to calculate the *relative risk*, not the odds ratio. The crude odds ratio is:

(Exposed Cases / Exposed Controls) / (Unexposed Cases / Unexposed Controls)

In this example:

(23/43) / (78/244) = 0.5348837/0.3196721 = 1.67

For the second part of your question, I don't believe that you can, because 0.3519 *isn't* the conditional odds of not being hypertensive, which is what the adjusted OR is using for its calculation. Beyond that, even if you can, it would only give you the event probability in the study itself, not the population as a whole (case-control studies are deliberately non-random samples intended to approximate risk, not calculate it directly).